# How can I reuse assertions between rails tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I have two tests that share the same set of assertions:

```
class MyControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test "send mail and save to db" do
    ...
    assert_equal 1, User.count
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    assert_equal good_md5, Digest::MD5.hexdigest(attachment.decoded)
    assert_response :success
    ...

  test "send mail and don't save to db" do
    ...
    assert_equal 0, User.count
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    assert_equal good_md5, Digest::MD5.hexdigest(attachment.decoded)
    assert_response :success
    ...
end
```

What can I do to reuse these assertions, so I don't have to repeat them in each test?

```
assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
assert_equal good_md5, Digest::MD5.hexdigest(attachment.decoded)
assert_response :success
```

I tried to put them into a module, but I was not able to use include inside the test blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it will work in ActionController::TestCase, but I tend to put shared tests (and other things) at the end of my file as stand-alone methods that I can call from my tests. Something like:

```
  class MyControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    test "send mail and save to db" do 
      ...
      test_values = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
      test_values[:user_count] = 1
      test_values[:deliveries] = 1
      test_values[:md5]        = good_md5
      validate_values test_values
    end 
  end

  def validate_values(test_values)
    assert_equal test_values[:user_count], User.count
    assert_equal test_values[:deliveries], ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    assert_equal test_values[:md5], Digest::MD5.hexdigest(attachment.decoded)
    assert_response :success
  end
```

There are lots of variations - you could just send in values instead of putting them in a hash, you could contruct your test values so that you could do a loop around your assert_equal so you only have to write it once, etc.

Anyhoo. Hope that helps.